# Value transfer issue

Tags: ios, nslog

Is there any explanation why the NSLog always displays null when running this code?

```
ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController *extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController =   [[ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController alloc] init];
extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.userImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icone_SideBar.png"];
NSLog(@"%@", extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.userImageView.image);
```

2014-10-28 13:40:50.594 E-proinfo[913:51418] (null)

Comment: By "returns" you mean "displays"? If `NSLog()` displays "null" it is  because `extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.userImageView.image` is `null`. So perhaps the question should be "Why does `extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.userImageView.image` return `null`?"

Comment: maybe because userImageView is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential causes:

- Your `ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController init` returned `nil` because there was an error during initialization.

  ```
  NSLog(@"%@", extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController); // Does this display '(null)'?
  ```
- Your `userImageView` isn't initialized yet because you don't initialize it in `ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController init`.

  ```
  NSLog(@"%@", extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.userImageView); // Does this display '(null)'?
  ```
- Your `image` is `nil` because you don't have an image named Icone_SideBar.png.

You should either add `NSLog` statements or add a breakpoint and use `po` to inspect your objects.

**Edit**:
If you want to set something on your view controller before your view is created (or as a persistent thing between view creations if you expect your view controller to destroy its view and then recreate it at some point), you should use a property.

Consider the following:

```
@interface ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController
@property (strong) UIImage *myUserImage;
...
@end

@implementation ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController
...
- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];
  ...
  [self.userImageView setImage:self.myUserImage];
  ...
}
...
@end

...
  ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController *extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController =   [[ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController alloc] init];
  extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.myUserImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icone_SideBar.png"];
```

Comment: When running
NSLog(@"%@", extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController);
2014-10-28 14:08:18.015 E-proinfo[1026:194071] <ExtratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController: 0x7ff6097cfc70>
was displayed

When running
NSLog(@"%@", extratoDeNotasSideMenuViewController.userImageView);
2014-10-28 14:08:18.015 E-proinfo[1026:194071] (null)
Was displayed

Comment: So then the second bullet applies... Your `userImageView` is `nil` because you aren't initializing it in your view controller's `init`. You're probably initializing it in your `viewDidLoad` or `loadView`, neither of which will have been called yet.